# Preserving multiple space in pytesseract python

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am working on project ,where i converting scanned image to text, i am using python pytesseract.image_to_string, everything working fine, i get text file, but problem is text file not preserved multiple space between column.It is taking only one space between the columns, I am using python2.7, ubuntu 14.04.

my code 
url = "/home/raghu/raghu2.png"
img = Image.open(url)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
print text

Is there any configuration so that i can put in above line.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810566/python-pytesseract-extracts-incorrect-text-from-image/51964830#51964830 -- Good Luck --

Comment: Thanks, i got the solution.  just put as config='-c preserve_interword_spaces=1' in tessaract will work.

Comment: Another similar link (for preserving completeness) is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668339/preserving-spaces-in-tesseract thanks