# Preserving Spaces in Tesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I had an image file, which contain some text separated by tabs (2 spaces). But when I extract text out of this image file, I always get a single space between two columns. A sample example:

IMAGE:

```
col-a    col-b    col-c
```

Desired output:

```
col-a    col-b    col-c
```

But I am getting the following:

```
col-a col-b col-c
```

I am using pytesseract.image_to_string (Python module) convert image to text

Answer (score 12):

Use it like this:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='-c preserve_interword_spaces=1')
```

Comment: I tried this but am getting the same output in both the cases - preserve_interword_spaces=1 and preserve_interword_spaces=0

Comment: `preserve_interword_spaces=1` is not available anymore with tesseract 4. May be it will be fixed later.

Comment: Hi guys, have you got this fixed?

Comment: This has been fixed. See https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/781

Comment: What is the difference between tesseract and pytesseract?  When I download pytesseract the latest version is 0.3.7.  When I download tesseract the latest version is 0.1.3.  At github they're saying that there is a version 4.  How do I get version 4 and how do I get python to use it?