# Preserve interword spaces in Pytesseract

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to get `pytesseract` to preserve interword spacing on an image.  This is especially important in scanning poetry.

```
 from PIL import Image
 import pytesseract
 img1 = Image.open(file)
 custom_config = r'-c preserve_interword_spaces=1 --psm 4'
 str4 = pytesseract.image_to_string(img1, config=custom_config)
```

I have also tried all types of `psm` configurations and other config options.  I'm also using the most uptodate version of pytesseract which is 0.3.7.

This question has already been asked many times.  Most notably here:
[Preserving Spaces in Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668339/preserving-spaces-in-tesseract)
However, the solution is not satisfactory.  It is recommended to see the following page:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/781
But at that page they assert that the problem has been solved here
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/commit/e62e8f5f802c0d8f3dd67da993327cdafaee9763
But on that page it seems that you have to upgrade to `tesseract 5.0` and I can't figure out how to do that on a mac, since `brew install` only installs `tesseract 4.0`.

I think if I could install tesseract 5.0 then that might solve the problem.

##################

UPDATE

Ok, I have confirmation on another site that I do have to upgrade to Tesseract 5.0.  `brew install` does not enable that on a mac. So I guess I have to learn how to pull tesseract 5.0 straight from github which I'm not very good at doing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to clone the repository and build it.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html#macos

Btw, `preserve_interword_spaces` works in Tesseract 4.1.1 also, if you can install that version.

Comment: Actually it turns out that it can preserve interword spaces but not the space at the beginning of a line, so-called identations. I'm working on a work around now but it is not easy.